# Storing a huge amount of points(x,y,z) in a relational database

Tags: sql, sqlite, data-structures, rdbms, bigdata

I need to store a very simple data structure on disk - the `Point`. It's fields are just:

- `Moment` - 64-bit integer, representing a time with high precision.
- `EventType` - 32-bit integer, reference to another object.
- `Value` - 64-bit floating point number.

Requirements:

1. The pair of (`Moment` + `EventType`) is unique identifier of the `Point`, so I suspect it to be a composite primary key.
2. There's a huge number of `Points`. Up to 5 billions (1-2 TB of disk space). So the format must be as small as possible.
3. Typical and almost single usage of the table is a retrieval (or creating a view) of millions of `Points` by exact `EventType` and a range of `Moments`.

Questions:

- Which RDBMS to choose and why?
- What is the optimal SQL definition for a table of `Points`?
- And comments about my thoughts below are also appreciated.

I don't need a huge professional system with all tools, features and extensions like PostgreSQL or MSSQL. Also I don't need a server, so the choice of SQLite looks optimal. Another great RDBMS with a feature of embedded database is Firebird, but I was seduced by SQLite's dynamic typing paradigm. It looks like it can save me space on disk because integer fields can be stored in "smaller" form (1, 2, 3, 4, 6 bytes).

But first of all, SQLite creates special `ROWID` column (64-bits length) when primary key is composite:

```
CREATE TABLE points (
    moment integer not null,
    event_id integer not null,
    value numeric not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (moment, event_id)
);
```

It means table wastes nearly 40% more space for nothing. I found ["The WITHOUT ROWID Optimization"](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/withoutrowid.html). But it will be available only in 3.8.2 version of SQLite (December 2013). Waiting for ADO.NET provider which I need is inappropriate.

Another problem is SQLite uses [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for tables. It looks like it is inefficient for selecting data ranges. To select a big block of `Points` based on primary key's range it looks SQLite will be a bad choice.

Comment: Why do you think B-trees are bad? What other table organization do you think would be more efficient?

Comment: @CL I think it is bad for my purpose. Simply sorted data will be easier to select by range.

Comment: "Simple sorted data" does not allow random accesses, and cannot ensure that the data stays sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B-trees are the most efficient organization for selecting data ranges.

If you search a constant `event_id` value and a range of `moment` values, the two-column index can be used for both lookups only if the `event_id` is the first column in the index:

```
CREATE TABLE points (
    event_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    moment INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id, moment)
);
```

You should try to use version 3.8.2 so that you can use the WITHOUT ROWID optimization.
The [developers](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/support.wiki) are likely to be happy that somebody will test this function, and give you a compiled prerelease version.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your table will be use more than one user you should not use embedded DB

What about Oracle - table organized by index (by event perhaps)  + partitioning by range

or MySql partition by range

if in your application will be really one user, maybe you can use file system ?

something like partitioned table

you can create folder with name related to range

and create files with name related with event_id so you need store in file only moment + data

even more for example your moment look like

201311141820001234567890123456

 you can create folder with name 2013111418 and store in file only part of moment and data

20001234567890123456,data

20001234567890123457,data

Comment: Only one user. FS will use much more space, will be inneficient for queries and hard to implement and support